# Prolog. How to access the members of a list in a fact?

Tags: prolog

Suppose, I have a fact with list:

```
members([a,b,c,d]).
```

How to write rule:

```
ismember(X) %returns 'Yes' only if X is a or b or c or d.
```

Needed a solution with pure Prolog, without any libraries.

Comment: This is simply an exercise in writing your own `member/2` function (`member(X, L)` is true if `X` is a member of `L`). It's only a couple of lines and you can find examples in a variety of places on the 'net.

Comment: Also, make sure to figure out if you actually need a predicate with the semantics of `member/2` or with the semantics of `memberchk/2`.

Comment: As you know, the aim of StackOverflow is to help people with programming problems. A course assignment is not a "problem" by itself. What did you try which failed?

Comment: Thank you, mrbatch and Aurelien, looks like I did incorrect explanation about what I need.
I don't need "member of list" as itself. I stucked exactly in 'how to access list, which declared in facts'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we need predicate `member(X, List)`. Or `member1`:

```
member1(X, [X|_]).
member1(X, [_|T]) :- member1(X, T).
```

So, rule `ismember` will looks like:

```
ismember(X):-
  members(List),
  member(X, List). %or member1 if we need to define membership rule
```

Comment: You probably mean `member1` called in your `ismember/1` predicate rather than just `member` since the latter is an ISO prolog library call, which I think you said you're trying to avoid. As I mentioned in my other comment, this question/problem is all about just writing your own version of the standard `member/2` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a predicate `ismember/1` that succeeds if the argument is contained in the list in `members/1`? i.e., if your fact was `members([1,2,3])`, would `ismember(X)` still succeed if X was a, b, c or d? If you need a unary predicate, then maybe you don't actually want to look into the `members/1` fact; if you need a binary predicate, then you need your own `member/2` predicate, as mrbatch said above...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Spyros. This should probably be a comment, not an answer, since it's not providing a final answer for the user but rather asking questions for clarification and making conditional suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @mrbatch - indeed it should have been a comment!